# Kentico 9 get data submitted by form

Tags: kentico

My company uses Kentico 9 for some forms that emails to users on submit. Where does the data object get created to be sent as an email? I am trying to get the form submit data, serialize it and post it to an api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kentico creates a dedicate SQL Server table for each form.  You can get the data via the API. Here's an example of loading form data using the Kentico 9 API:

https://docs.kentico.com/api9/content-management/form-data

Mike

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a [custom event handler](https://docs.kentico.com/k9/custom-development/handling-global-events/reference-global-system-events#Reference-Globalsystemevents-BizFormItemEvents) on insert of the of the bizform item records.  This way you can utilize all the data which is submitted with the form AND perform other activities if you need.